# style (jquery) checkbox button in IE to wrap automatically

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Due to the length of the code I can not post it here, I have created a [demo page](http://repository.awardspace.us/debug/search.htm).

1. Using IE to open the page.
2. Click on "Add" link.
3. Then, click on "Specify Request types".

Bellow is a screenshot from IE8:

[image: screenshot from IE8]

You should be able to see the desired layout when view the page using Chrome, Safari and Firefox

[image: screenshot from Chrome]
This is a screenshot from Chrome.

For IE, I have tried to put the list of `checkbox` into a div(#request_type) and set its `width` (to something like 150px), hope that the `checkbox` list will wrap around, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you post an image of how you see it. For me it doesnt work at all in IE9, IE7 looks similar to chrome?

Comment: I loaded your demo page in IE8, and I could not reproduce your problem. The list wraps around correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a consistent look simply define your `label` elements as `display:inline-block` for IE only by using a conditional comment that you can place in the header of your document, like so:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
.ui-button {
    display: inline-block;
}
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what's going on here, but floating the labels helps to keep the items within their own column:

```
#request_type label {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went to your URL above and don't see any buttons.

A note on your accepted answer. `display: inline-block` doesn't always work well in IE7 if that is a supported browser for your page/app.